# Selenium Grid: Mac failed to connect Windows hub with UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: selenium

I have a selenium project in Mac and I want to connect to a Windows hub to run test scripts, but it always failed with **UnreachableBrowserException**:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 30.5.43.101:4444 [/30.5.43.101] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
```

My question is :
does selenium grid support cross platform hub connection? If yes, can you guys give some tips on setup?

```
public void setUp() {
String node = "http://windowsnodeip:4444/wd/hub";
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

try {
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(node),capabilities);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is the **windowsnodeip** in the node variable? Is it the grid IP address ?

Comment: Update the question with your HUB & NODE starting commands

Comment: thanks all, it turns out i didn't allow java SE in my firewall options